# JsonBigDecimalNumber incompatible with javax json JsonString

Tags: java, json

I have a jsonObject. I would like to extract values from it. The type of the field that I would like to extract it is `long`

My code:

```
JsonObject rec = my_files.getJsonObject(i);                 
JsonString timestamps = rec.getJsonString("timestamps");
```

I got an exception when getting t:

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.glassfish.json.JsonNumberImpl$JsonBigDecimalNumber incompatible with javax.json.JsonString
```

As my understanding, the exception telling me that I'm trying to convert `JSONNumber` into `JsonString`.

How can I extract the `timestamps` field please ?
Thanks

Comment: declare your variable to be of type `JsonBigDecimalNumber` or `JsonNumber` perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use  `getJsonNumber`

```
JsonObject rec = my_files.getJsonObject(i);                 
JsonNumber timestamps = rec.getJsonNumber("timestamps");
```

For more informations see:

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html#getJsonNumber-java.lang.String-